# What is the difference between Datatable.js and Dynatable.js?

Tags: datatable, dynatable

I have around 300,000 data to be showned in table and i used datatable.js but is too much slow as it gathers all the data and paginates it which really annoys. while searching the option i found dynatable.js.
Can Somebody tell me the difference between these two??

Comment: Check datatable [server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) it allow you to load x rows at a time

Answer (score 3):

There aren't massive differences between the two libraries - I've used both and can say they are pretty much the same thing. Dynatable is more snazzy, with more options for cool front end features, whereas datatables is more rigid. Dynatables allows you to write custom table sorting features (which was a must-have for me).

The most important thing is that dynatable (although it looks cool) still has a lot of bugs, and from what it looks like (last commit to git was in '14), the developer has discontinued the project.